# How to display matrix cursor using list adapter in Android?

Tags: sql, android, matrix, cursor, listadapter

I am trying to add row to the cursor (which is done with matrix cursor), then pass the cursor to the list adapter (resource adapter). The list adapter takes only a cursor. How do I add a row to the list adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add a row to the list adapter. You just add a row to the matrix cursor like this:

```
mx.newRow().add(0).add("value of second column").add("value of third column");
mx.newRow().add(1).add("value of second column").add("value of third column");
```

...
etc.
Then with a SimpleCursorAdapter you "connect" the MatrixCursor to the ListAdapter