# Need a quick way to do a SearchView with suggested text (MatrixCursor?)

Tags: android, cursor, searchview

I have a search feature in my fragment that allows the user to search for all the icons i have in my app.

Right now i have a loading activity when the app starts to load all the icons into a SQLiteDatabase FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE.

Even on my Nexus 5 it takes about 30 seconds or so to load 1200 icon names.

I have them loading like this in an async task

```
final String[] extras2 = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icon_pack);
    for (String extra : extras2) {
        String uri = "drawable/" + extra;
        int res = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, mContext.getPackageName());
        if (res != 0) {
            ob.setNumber(res);
        }
    }
    final String[] extras = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icon_pack_names);
    for (String extra : extras) {
        ob.setText(extra);
        publishProgress(extra);
    }
```

And then thats loaded into my SQLiteDatabase with this Async task

```
mDbHelper = new SearchDbHelper(mContext);
    mDbHelper.open();

    for (int i = 0; i < myObject.getSize(); i++){
        mDbHelper.createList(myObject.getText().get(i),myObject.getNumber().get(i));
        Integer progress = (100 * i) / myObject.getSize();
        publishProgress(progress);
    }

    return mDbHelper;
```

Then in my fragment when options menu is created

```
 @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu");
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.icon_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frame);
            frame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frame);
            frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Then when search option is selected it runs this method

```
public void doSearch(){
    Log.i(TAG, "doSearch");

    mCategoryList = ThemeApp.getSearchIcons();

    if (mCategoryList == null){
        Log.i(TAG, "mCategoryList == null");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InitializeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }else{
        myList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);
        defaultAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(getActivity(), mCategoryList);
        myList.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(IconsFrag.this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(IconsFrag.this);
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();

        mDbHelper = new SearchDbHelper(getActivity());
        mDbHelper.open();
    }
}
```

Finally, this is how it displays results

```
private void displayResults(String query) {
    Boolean click = ClickBoolean.getValue();
    Log.i(TAG,query);
    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchByInputText((query != null ? query : "@@@@"));
    Log.i(TAG,cursor.toString());
    if (cursor != null) {
        String[] from = new String[] {SearchDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME, String.valueOf(SearchDbHelper.COLUMN_URI)};

        // Specify the view where we want the results to go
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.list_item_text_view, R.id.wp_thumb};

        // Create a simple cursor adapter to keep the search data
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.icon_search_result, cursor, from, to);
        myList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        if(click)
        // Click listener for the searched item that was selected
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Integer selectedName = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("uri"));

                Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(selectedName));
                IntentUtil.endWithIcon(getActivity(), selectedName);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**2 problems**
1- Im getting a crash if the app is left in background and user opens it later and tries to search.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.**.**.icons.search.SearchListAdapter.getCount(SearchListAdapter.java:33)
at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
at com.**.**.icons.Icons_app.doSearch(Icons_app.java:148)
at com.**.**.icons.Icons_app.onOptionsItemSelected(Icons_app.java:128)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2774)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:979)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:523)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:116)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3528)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14244)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

2- There has to be a way to do this without loading into a database and needing a loading screen. I have seen other apps that do this and my research shows its done with a MatrixCursor?

Please help me figure this out..

Comment: yes, you dont need sqlite db to get the Cursor, the easiest is to use a MatrixCursor

Comment: any help on implementing? I have looked at it but can't seem to grap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531031/how-to-display-matrix-cursor-using-list-adapter-in-android